# How to get the column of parse.com class?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I trying to use Cloud Code to get class's data.

And there are my questions.
[image]

Q:In this photo,how do I get the score column?

there is my code.

```js
var object = [];
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query('Meeting');
pushQuery.find({
success: function(results) {
                success: function(results) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                object[i] = results[i];
                        }
                },
                error: function(error) {
                }
        });
```

Comment: have u got a solution or not?

Comment: I tried,but I got nothing.

Comment: are u getting any errors or not?

Comment: Look downstairs,please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get column from parse one of following ways.

```
 results[i].get("columnName").
```

or

```
results[i].ansId //replace ansId with your column name.
```